# How to count the number of characters without "-" and "()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an input field for the phone numbers and field length counter. How can I ignore "-", spaces, and "()" in the field when I count its length? 
I mean, if the input value looks like "(099) 99-99", its length when I call `val().length` should be 7, and not 11.

```
var phoneInput = getElementById("phone");
var counter = getElementById("lengthCounter");

counter.text(phoneInput.val().length);
```

Comment: `String#replace` takes a regular expression. `\D` is a pattern that will match things that are not digits.

Comment: `phoneInput.val().replace(/[^\d]/g,'').length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will replace anything that is NOT a number with an empty sting.

```
counter.text(phoneInput.val().replace(/[^\d]/g, '').length)
```

Comment: @VladimirHumeniuk, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using regular expression.`\D` matches all the `non-digit` characters and the `g` is `global` modifier for regular expression.`Replace` all non-digits with empty string then count length of your string.

```js
var string = "(099) 99-99";
console.log(string.replace(/\D/g,'').length);
```

Comment: This will crash if the input contains no digits.

Comment: @ nnnnnn agree with you need to replace non-digit characters with empty string.

Comment: This answer was `console.log(string.match(/\d/g).length);` and when @nnnnnn wrote the comment, the answer was changed .. Just for transparency and to understand the comment of @nnnnnn

Answer (score 1):

By replacing all occurrences of that chars by empty string , then length of the output is what you are looking for.

```
const  value = phoneInput.val();

value.replace(/[\-\(\)]/g, '').length // replace "-", "(", ")" by empty string
```

```js
const phoneInput = document.querySelector('input');
const  value = phoneInput.value;
    
 console.log(   
    value.replace(/[\-\(\)]/g, '').length
 )
```

```html
<input value="(32)-(123)-(4444)" />
```

Comment: This answer respects well the question: length of a string **WITHOUT** certain characters

Answer (score 0):

Check this out! no need to write many lines of code.

```js
function count() {
    var x = document.getElementById("phonenumber");
    var count = x.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"").length;
    $("#displaycount").text("Number Count "+count);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Enter your Number: <input type="text" placeholder="example (99) 99-999" id="phonenumber" onkeyup="count()">
<br/><br/>
<div id="displaycount"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace [none digit (\D)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit_non.asp) by "" and then count the length of new string.

```js
var phoneNum = "(+84) 122 - 384 - 6471";
var count = phoneNum.replace(/\D/g, "").length;
alert(count);
```